# How can I make a "global link to a folder" in terminal

Tags: command-line

I'm afraid I am sure this has been answered somewhere, but I guess it's not called "global link", so I wasn't capable of finding exactly what I needed.

Basically I currently have written a script in /usr/bin, that does what I want:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=~/ownCloud/folder/subfolder
if [ -d $dir  ]
then
        konsole --workdir $dir &
else
        echo "a problem occured"
fi
```

Now, the problem is that this will open a new terminal.
And I am quite sure that there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly, that you run in a terminal or text screen and want a command to change directory to a certain directory? What about a simple `cd "$dir"` instead of involving `konsole`?

Comment: How do you use your script. Show an example, please.

Comment: @sudodus, that doesn't work for a reason which I can not correctly tell you here. Something to do with thatthe bash script starts running in a seaparate task/environment/...(?) or something

Comment: @Gyru scripts that are in /usr/bin/ are called by typing it's name into the terminal

Comment: And how are you calling (or want to call) this script? You write that it is a problem that this will open a new terminal. It does because `konsole` is a terminal emulator program. Please tell us more precisely how you use it and what you want.

Comment: @sudodus, basically I just want to type "name" into the terminal at any point, and be redirected to a folder

Comment: Maybe the simplest solution to that is an alias: for example you can try with the following command line `alias cd1='cd ~/ownCloud/folder/subfolder'`, When you have tested that it works, you can store it in your bash configuaration file `~/.bashrc` next to the already existing aliases in that file. Then, when you start a terminal window, the alias will be active, and you have a convenient way to get to that directory.

Answer (score 1):

> basically I just want to type "name" into the terminal at any point, and be redirected to a folder

Open the document `~/.bashrc` and add at the bottom:

```
alias name='cd ~/ownCloud/folder/subfolder'
```

Then open a terminal and run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Type `name` inyour terminal and it will go to the dir you wanted.

Comment: perfect, thank you